# QEMU msi emulation

Tags: linux, qemu, pci, pci-e, irq

I am working on an emulated QEMU device to simulate an FPGA PCIe interface. I am using the lev-pci device as a base template:

https://github.com/levex/kernel-qemu-pci/blob/master/qemu/hw/char/lev-pci.c

My device uses MSI interrupts to communicate.  The kernel driver module is capable of enabling the MSI interrupts and receiving them.  I have modified lev-pci.c to add

```
msi_init(dev, 0x70, 1, false, false);
```

to the initialization and then

```
msi_notify(pci_dev,0);
```

to the "pci_levdev_read"  function as a basic test.  I can trace that the msi interrupt is being generated in the debugger but I am not receiving the interrupt on the host.  Am I missing a step to enable the MSI interrupts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to enable DMA in the kernel module.

```
pci_set_dma_mask(pdev, DMA_BIT_MASK(32))
pci_set_master(pdev)
```

Comment: If the question is solved, please mark your own question as answered.

Comment: Your answer gives a LOT LOT help, which saves me from hell. This problem blocks for a couple of days last week. I posted a this problem to QEMU-devel mail list, but there is no reply.

Comment: Glad it was useful. I had this problem because my old testbench didn't have an IOMMU so it worked on hardware but not QEMU. Drove me crazy for about a week.